# SELECT only rows that contain only alphanumeric characters in MySQL

Tags: mysql, regex

I'm trying to select all rows that contain only alphanumeric characters in MySQL using:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

However, it's returning all rows, regardless of the fact that they contain non-alphanumeric characters.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Try this code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$'
```

This makes sure that all characters match.

Comment: Okey it done properly, but it does not show space including data field. How do i get space including data field by this query.

Comment: @Md.MahabuburRahman: All a blank between `9` and `]`: `'^[A-Za-z0-9 ]+$'`

Comment: is regexp efficient?  I remember doing this with isnumeric on the last character.  this is interesting.  thanks select name from birt
 where isnumeric(RIGHT(name,1)) =1

Comment: @chungtinhlakho No, regexp is very inefficient compared to `isnumeric()` Use specialized functions when you can.

Answer (score 10):

Your statement matches any string that contains a letter or digit anywhere, even if it contains other non-alphanumeric characters. Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[A-Za-z0-9]+$';
```

`^` and `$` require the entire string to match rather than just any portion of it, and `+` looks for 1 *or more* alphanumberic characters.

You could also use a named character class if you prefer:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '^[[:alnum:]]+$';
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
REGEXP '^[a-z0-9]+$'
```

As regexp is not case sensitive except for binary fields.

Answer (score 1):

There is also this:

```
select m from table where not regexp_like(m, '^[0-9]\d+$')
```

which selects the rows that contains characters from the column you want (which is m in the example but you can change).

Most of the combinations don't work properly in Oracle platforms but this does. Sharing for future reference.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
select count(*) from table where cast(col as double) is null;
```

Answer (score -7):

Change the `REGEXP` to `Like`

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_name like '%[^a-zA-Z0-9]%'
```

this one works fine