# SQL Select Statement(REGEXP) to find special characters and numbers in an alpha only field

Tags: mysql, sql, regex, talend

I am using mySQL to query a field which would be `LastName`. I am looking for any errors in the field such as any special characters or numbers. I am not terribly familiar with SQL so this has been a challenge so far. I have written simple statements with `REGEXP` but I have run into some issues the `REGEXP` i was using was:

```
SELECT LastName FROM `DB`.`PLANNAME` where LastName REGEXP '^([0-9])'
```

now this turned up results where numbers were the first character in the string and i realized that if anything was in the middle of the string that started with a letter this would not pick it out.

To be clear i just need to find the errors not write a code to clean them out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Pete

Comment: Remove the `^`, if you want to find the pattern in the middle of the string.

Comment: so is there anything to find special characters like parentheses or periods or commas that i could write in the same statement

Comment: Do you just want non-alpha characters found (or the inverse)? I think this thread would solve that, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1471523/select-only-rows-that-contain-only-alphanumeric-characters-in-mysql (take out the `0-9`).

Comment: that is correct Chris l only want non alpha characters found

Comment: So `^[A-Za-z]+$` will find all the correct ones?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it for you.

```
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[^A-Za-z]'
```

This will return any rows where a character that is not a-z. You might want to add in  and `'`. For `O'brien`s and `von lansing` etc. Any characters you think are acceptable should go in the character class `[]`, http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nC9cG7/1

Comment: Great, please mark this as the accepted answer when you have tested this thoroughly; or post issues/questions you encounter. http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Chris i tried adding hyphens and an apostrophe in the character class however even within brackets ' is just ending my code, and the [-] is still returning results with hyphens any idea on this?

Comment: Try escaping the hyphen and quote. The hyphen usually designates a range and the quote closes the regex encapsulation. `SELECT column FROM table WHERE column REGEXP '[^A-Za-z\-\']'`. That's untested, if it doesn't work let me know and I'll run a test..

Comment: i had to put a space between the a-z and \-\ that got rid of the hyphens however the ' is still closing the expression and throwing errors "unterminated string literal" becuase its seeing the ]' as a different section even when i double the '' it works but then shows the hyphens again and still shows names with apostrophes

Comment: and im not sure if this matters but i am running these expressions in talend SQL editor

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure why that's not working but I've encountered the same issue here. Try this solution, `SELECT column FROM table WHERE column NOT REGEXP '([:alpha:]|-|\')'`

Comment: If you're interested in the why the first query failed I've started a question on it because I'm unsure, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31751034/mysql-regex-error-1139-using-literal.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT LastName FROM `DB`.`PLANNAME` WHERE NOT LastName REGEXP '[A-Za-z0-9]';
```

Here is a documentation on this:

[**Table 12.9 String Regular Expression Operators**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html)